# unable to get gps location in certain devices in android

Tags: android, gps

In my android application i am trying to get the gps location on a button click. i have tried many examples but the examples work on certain devices. The device on which i am testing i.e Micromax A90S, i am unable to get a location on it. i am unable to find out what exactly is the issue. Is it the device or do i need to do some changes in my code??? The code i am using is given below

```
protected void showCurrentLocation() {

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}   

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Please help!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a

Comment: @praveenSharma this example too only keeps searching for gps location and does not give any result

Comment: once you got the location store this info in some variable. Use some global var for it so that it will refresh accordingly.

Comment: @praveenSharma it does work on some device like samsung tab..i have tried that..but the one which i am using it does not display..m storing the values also in some global variable..

Comment: are you getting some error?

Comment: i do not get the location for the first time..it just keeps on searching and refreshing evry 20secs..

Comment: 20 sec its just a timer you can modify it own way and you can remove also. but are you getting the location after 20 sec. for your device?

Comment: @praveenSharma no after 20 secs also i dont get the location

Comment: implement LocationListener directly to the activity

Comment: also check whether you have put following permission in manifest or not. 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>